# Spring server.forward-headers-strategy NATIVE vs FRAMEWORK

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-hateoas

I recently upgraded spring boot from 1.x to 2.y and was facing this issue where hateoas links were generated with `http` scheme instead of `https`.

Later I discovered that with spring boot 2.2+, it is mandatory to use the following property

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
```

which can have one of `NATIVE` or `FRAMEWORK` or `NONE`.

`NONE` property is pretty straight forward and it totally disables use of forward headers.

But there is no clear documentation on `NATIVE` vs `FRAMEWORK`. I've seen in many places it is mentioned that `NATIVE` works the best in most cases. But there is no explanation on what exactly happens behind the scenes when we use these properties.

The [documentation here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/8b732a9c330c479d4ab1ff79d5842cbbc89b9515/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L1700-L1717) doesn't give enough information for me to choose between Native/Framework. All it says is who handles the forwarded headers for corresponding values. Servlet container? or Spring framework? but it brings back to square 1. Should I let container handle it? or the framework? when Should I prefer one over the other?

I am using REST web application with external tomcat and `Hateoas` for generating the links.

How do I decide whether to use  `NATIVE` or `FRAMEWORK` property? When should one be preferred over the other and why?

My springboot version: `2.4.6`

**References I've already tried:**

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18667
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-22
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#filters-forwarded-headers
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#filters-forwarded-headers

**EDIT:**

I tried both the solutions and `framework` works for me but not `native` in external tomcat environment. I created a new spring boot web application with embedded tomcat and both `native` and `framework` works.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### FRAMEWORK

`FRAMEWORK` uses Spring's support for handling forwarded headers. For example, Spring Boot auto creates an `ForwardedHeaderFilter` bean for Spring MVC when `server.forward-headers-strategy=framework`.

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingFilterBean(ForwardedHeaderFilter.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "server.forward-headers-strategy", havingValue = "framework")
public FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    ForwardedHeaderFilter filter = new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR);
    registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return registration;
}
```

`ForwardedHeaderFilter` handles non-standard headers `X-Forwarded-Host`, `X-Forwarded-Port`, `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Forwarded-Ssl`, and `X-Forwarded-Prefix`.

### NATIVE

`NATIVE` uses the underlying container's native support for forwarded headers. The underlying container means tomcat, jetty, netty, etc. For example, the embedded Tomcat which is auto-configured by Spring Boot handles non-standard headers `X-Forwarded-Host`, `X-Forwarded-Port`, `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Forwarded-Ssl`, but not `X-Forwarded-Prefix`.

### X-Forwarded-Prefix

For example, API gateway runs on `localhost:8080` and api service `sga-booking` runs on `localhost:20000`. API gateway route `/sga-booking` is forwarded to api service `sga-booking`.
The request to `localhost:8080/sga-booking` contains headers:

```
forwarded = proto=http;host="localhost:8080";for="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:46706"
x-forwarded-for = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0
x-forwarded-proto = http
x-forwarded-prefix = /sga-booking
x-forwarded-port = 8080
x-forwarded-host = localhost:8080
host = 192.168.31.200:20000
```

When `ForwardedHeaderFilter` handles forwarded headers including `X-Forwarded-Prefix`, generated links starts with `localhost:8080/sga-booking`. If `X-Forwarded-Prefix` is not handled, generated links starts with `localhost:8080`.

### Embedded Tomcat auto-configured by Spring Boot

With property `server.forward-headers-strategy=native`, method
`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer#customizeRemoteIpValve` configures a `RemoteIpValve` with properties `server.tomcat.remoteip` (`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.Tomcat.Remoteip`) to handle forwarded headers. Note that `X-Forwarded-Prefix` is not handled.

```java
private void customizeRemoteIpValve(ConfigurableTomcatWebServerFactory factory) {
    Remoteip remoteIpProperties = this.serverProperties.getTomcat().getRemoteip();
    String protocolHeader = remoteIpProperties.getProtocolHeader();
    String remoteIpHeader = remoteIpProperties.getRemoteIpHeader();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(protocolHeader) || StringUtils.hasText(remoteIpHeader)
        || getOrDeduceUseForwardHeaders()) {
        RemoteIpValve valve = new RemoteIpValve();
        valve.setProtocolHeader(StringUtils.hasLength(protocolHeader) ? protocolHeader : "X-Forwarded-Proto");
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(remoteIpHeader)) {
            valve.setRemoteIpHeader(remoteIpHeader);
        }
        valve.setInternalProxies(remoteIpProperties.getInternalProxies());
        try {
            // X-Forwarded-Host by default
            valve.setHostHeader(remoteIpProperties.getHostHeader());
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodError ex) {
            // Avoid failure with war deployments to Tomcat 8.5 before 8.5.44 and
            // Tomcat 9 before 9.0.23
        }
        // X-Forwarded-Port by default
        valve.setPortHeader(remoteIpProperties.getPortHeader());
        valve.setProtocolHeaderHttpsValue(remoteIpProperties.getProtocolHeaderHttpsValue());
        factory.addEngineValves(valve);
    }
}
```

### External Tomcat

// Sorry I haven't play vanilla Tomcat for years after graduating from school. Below Tomcat info may be wrong.
To make external Tomcat handle forwarded headers, like what Spring Boot configures, I think A `RemoteIpValve` should be configured by add

```xml
<Context>
  ...
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
         hostHeader="X-Forwarded-Host"
         portHeader="X-Forwarded-Port"
       ...
  />
  ...
</Context>
```

to Tomcat `server.xml`? or `context.xml`?
Find all remote ip valve attributes [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve). Note that no attribute is related to `X-Forwarded-Prefix`.

Tomcat filter [`RemoteIpFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_IP_Filter) may have similar function. I don't know their difference.

### Reference

- [ServerProperties.ForwardHeadersStrategy Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.ForwardHeadersStrategy.html)
- [Spring Boot Reference Documentation about forwarded headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server)
- [Spring HATEOAS forwarded header handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#server.link-builder.forwarded-headers)

Comment: What exactly does it mean handling forwarded headers? How is the servlet container handling it is different from the framework handling it?

Comment: @ArunGowda answer is updated with example to explain the difference.

Comment: Does `native` / `framework` matter in external tomcat? Because, as I mentioned in my Edit, they behave differently. In embedded tomcat, both the values work with Hateoas while in external tomcat only `framework` works and not `native`.

Comment: Answering my own question above: `native` in external tomcat environment doesn't work. It only works with embedded tomcat. If you're using external tomcat and don't want to make any changes in external tomcat config, you have to go with `framework`